# mix-blend-mode difference mixed result

Tags: html, css

i have  mix-blend-mode difference it works fine but if something is overlapping the header it's changing the whole content of the header not just the overlapping area better images to get my point

all woks fine here the text is white so it turns black
[image]

but when an image is overlapping the header the colors are changing to white even the Macedonia word on the right all i need is to keep Macedonia black since the image is not overlapping it
[image]

```
<header id="header">
    <p class="header__role">An innovation company.</p>
    <h1 class="header__name">Watan —  N0.1</h1>
    <p class="header__location">Macedonia</p>
</header>
```

css

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 3.55556rem;
    padding: 0.44444rem 1.66667rem;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid hsla(0,0%,95.7%,.25);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__name {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

img {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 200vh;
}
```